# Using for loop to create subclass objects with Parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am tryng to create  posts using a for loop, but when i look at Parse database only the last object of my array get's stored. this is the code i wrote.

```
var Reggione = Parse.Object.extend("Reggione");
    var creaReggione = new Reggione();
    var selectobject = $('#searcharea')[0]; 

    for (var i = 2; i < selectobject.length; i++) {

        creaReggione.set("name", selectobject.options[i].text);
        creaReggione.save();
```

Thanks, Bye.

Answer (score 1):

Do this by creating an array of new objects, then save them together...

```
var newObjects = [];
for (var i = 2; i < selectobject.length; i++) {

    creaReggione.set("name", selectobject.options[i].text);
    newObjects.push(creaReggione);
    // ...
}
Parse.Object.saveAll(newObjects);
```

Remember, if you want something to happen after `saveAll` completes (like call `response.success()` if you're in cloud code), then you should use that promise as follows...

```
Parse.Object.saveAll(newObjects).then(function(result) {
    response.success(result);
}, function(error) {
    response.error(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In extension to danhs answer, the reason this does not work is because only one transaction can happen at a time from the JS client to Parse.

Therefore in your loop the first call to `.save()` is made and the object is saved to Parse at some rate (asynchrounously), in that time the loop continues to run and skips over your other save calls, these objects are NOT queued to be saved.   As Danh pointed out, you must use Parse's batch operations to save multiple objects to the server in one go, to do this you can:

```
var newObjects = [];
for (var i = 2; i < selectobject.length; i++) {

    creaReggione.set("name", selectobject.options[i].text);
    newObjects.push(creaReggione);
    // ...
}
Parse.Object.saveAll(newObjects);
```

Hope this helps, I'd also recommend taking a look at Parse's callback functions on the save method to get more details on what happened (you can check for errors and success callbacks here to make debugging a little easier)

An example of this would be to extend the previous call with:

```
Parse.Object.saveAll(newObjects, {
        success: function(messages) {
            console.log("The objects were successfully saved...")
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("An error occurred when saving the messages array: %s", error.message)
        }
    })
```

I hope this is of some help to you